# Can two methods point to the same code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, methods

I have a class which exposes two methods. These methods are actually visual syntax sugar, they ultimately point to the same code which behaves differently, depending on the payload it receives:

```
class Action:

    def on(self):
        self.action(1)

    def off(self):
        self.action(2)

    def action(self, payload):
        # a long function which does many things and uses the payload from on() and off()
        print(payload)

a = Action()
a.on()
a.off()
```

Is there a way to define `on()` and `off()` so that they point to the same code (the one in `action()`), which would **behave differently depending on the name of the method which was called?**

I could of course pass the action in the call:

```
class Action:

    def action(self, what):
        payload = 1 if what == 'on' else 0
        # a long function which does many things and uses the payload from on() and off()
        print(payload)


a = Action()
a.action('on')
a.action('off')
```

but I want to keep an on/off structure of the class methods.

Comment: try the state pattern https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state/python/1

Comment: What should happen if `action` is called by something other than `on` or `off`?

Comment: "which would behave differently depending on the name of the method which was called" - that's going to be a maintenance headache. What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything wrong with what you already have...especially given that the payloads are different for `on` and `off`.

Comment: @Kevin: there are safeguards for that in the actual code, I scaled it down to just highlight the problem I am having.

Comment: In general, *no* Python object knows anything about the name (or names) that are bound to it. What you have is the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to your first example, but are you looking for [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial)?

You can use it to automatically set some arguments into a function, and the return value is a function object as well.  Using it, you could do this:

```
import functools
class Abc(object):
  def action(self, payload):
    print(payload)
  def __init__(self):
    self.off = functools.partial(self.action, payload=1)
    self.on = functools.partial(self.action, payload=2)
```

Then, you have your `action`, `on`, and `off` function, all working as expected:

```
foo = Abc()
foo.on()
>>> 2
foo.off()
>>> 1
foo.action(9)
>>> 9
```

Using `partial` is a semantically stronger way to say that this is syntactic sugar for calling another function.  A function declaration such as `def on(self): ...` could be anything, while `self.on = functools.partial(action,...)` explicitly states that your tying one function to the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
def _action_maker(payload):
    def _action(self):
        return self.action(payload)

    return _action

class Action:
    on = _action_maker(1)
    off = _action_maker(2)

    def action(self, payload):
        # a long function which does many things and uses the payload from on() and off()
        print(payload)
```

But personally I don't like this because my editor doesn't understand it and gives me false warnings.

Answer (score -1):

### Try `inspect`

```
import inspect
class Action:

    def on(self):
        self.action(1)

    def off(self):
        self.action(2)

    def action(self, payload):
        # a long function which does many things and uses the payload from on() and off()
        currentframe = inspect.currentframe()
        callername = inspect.getouterframes(currentframe, 2)[1][3]
        if callername =='on':
            print('on')
        elif callername == 'off':
            print('off')

a = Action()
a.on() #on
a.off() #off
```

---

### Or simply pass hidden argument

```
class Action:

    def on(self):
        self.action(1,'on')

    def off(self):
        self.action(2, 'off')

    def action(self, payload, callername):
        # a long function which does many things and uses the payload from on() and off()
        if callername =='on':
            print('on')
        elif callername == 'off':
            print('off')

a = Action()
a.on() #on
a.off() #off
```

Comment: would you know whether the interface is stable? I am a bit worried about the various numerical indexes and parameters

Comment: @WoJ It is not guaranteed. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.currentframe . But I may suggest a simple workaround.